# Connect from docker container to service which is behind VPN

Tags: reactjs, docker, vpn

I have a specific issue.

My docker container hosts a dev enviroment of a React application.

This application uses an npm package hosted on a private gitlab package registry.

Private package registry is behind a VPN.

Host machine is connected to this VPN

Running yarn install, runs a request to package registry, which is unreachable (docker is using a no-vpn connection?)

How can I configure docker network to use host's VPN connection by default?

Comment: If you don't need the Docker container to have its own network, tell it to use the host network. `docker run --net=host`

Comment: unfortunatelly I do need it, whole service is divided between multiple containers which need to have own networks to avoid IP conflicts etc